# Trying to send pop-up notifications to Firebase through POSTMAN

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

im trying to send a pop up notification to my cellphone where i have intalled my android app through FIREBASE. Im getting an error while using POSTMAN (the key and id looks right to me from what ive been reading )...
**"{"multicast_id":171947496247984052,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MissingRegistration"}]}"** 
It seems that im having trouble with some kind of auth . i know that firebase use oAUTH 2.0 authentication and it request a token. Where or how can i get that token ? Im new at this and have absolutly no idea how.
Any ideas ? Please c:

Answer (score 0):

According to the error codes listed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), you're missing a registration token.

> Check that the request contains a registration token (in the registration_id in a plain text message, or in the to or registration_ids field in JSON).

The registration token is the unique token ID provided by the device that you want to send the message to.

Comment: Thanks man. I was thinking about that but didnt have it figure it out yet.

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, on Stack Overflow it's customary to upvote it and mark it as correct using the buttons on the left.